# How to make the Bootstrap 3 tooltip appear the same as in the documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

On Twitter Bootstrap 3, when you look at the Tooltip it appears like the one below.

[image: This is what appears on the Documentation]

When I tried doing it. This is how the tooltip appears.

[image]

This is the code I used.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">
    Tooltip on left
</button>
```

**Update**

This is my JS code

```
$('#tooltip1').tooltip('options')
```

Comment: activated first your tooltip.. `$('#example').tooltip(options)`

Comment: Enable tooltips everywhere by using  their data-toggle attribute `]$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put the `Tooltip on left` in `data-original-title="Tooltip on left"` and `id="tooltip1"` to match your script.

```
<button id="tooltip1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Tooltip on left">
    Tooltip on left
</button>
```

It was not working because your script references an id that you did not have and 'option' as a string.
options should be blank or something like 'show' or 'hide' but in your case it will work blank.

change:

```
$('#tooltip1').tooltip('options')
```

to:

```
$('#tooltip1').tooltip();
```

be sure to include the semi-colon.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a simple example

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Bootstrap Tool-Tip preview
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-6">
                    <button data-original-title="Tooltip on left" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="tooltip1">
                        Tooltip on left 
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script id="bsJs" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tooltip1').tooltip();
        });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

See Example: [bootply](http://bootply.com/87667)

Comment: but the tooltip still looks the same default. Not the one like in the Bootstrap 3 documentation?

Comment: Are your call using something like $('button').tooltip(); ? It is required. If you are, please show us more of your code.

Comment: I'm sure I followed your suggestions but now even the tooltip is not showing, can you make it in [bootply](http://bootply.com) ? It is like jsFiddle but for Bootstrap. I'm sorry if I can't understand, I don't really have a solid background in JS. And just begun studying it.

Comment: Thank you, it has finally worked. Had Minor issue. Should've have included the jQuery.js first before Bootstrap.js

Comment: Yes, the ordering of jquery and bootstrap is quite vital. jQuery.js b4 Bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1):

You need the "data-placement" with value "left"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">
    Tooltip on left
</button>
```

Remember to load the tooltip to all the place with data-toggle="tooltip", you need write with jQuery before of close the  this sentence :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Tooltip
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I aleardy put the data-placement and `<script>` codes but the appearance of the tooltips is still the same. Like an ordinary tooltip, not the one like in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work for me either until I changed the $ to jQuery. Once I changed it, the default bootstrap tooltip showed properly for me. So do this in your Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Tooltip
        jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

I hope that helps someone out!